# Arduino Random Number Generator with pushbutton

Tags: random, arduino, numbers

I'm new to Arduino, trying to make a random number generator with pushbutton.

My questions are:

1. How can I do that,if I press the pushbutton **once**, then I will get **one** random number between 0 and 1024. After that, I want to loop from 0 to the random number and then back to 0.
2. How can I debounce the pushbutton

Sample code:

```
void setup(){

    Serial.begin(57600);
    pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(0,randomnumber,FALLING);

}

void randomnumber(){

    int number=random(0,1024);
    for(int x=0;x<=number; x++){
      Serial.println(x);
      delay(1000);

  }

    for(int y=number;y>=0; y--){
      Serial.println(y);
      delay(1000);
  }

}
void loop(){

}
```

Any good suggestion?

Comment: What exactly is the problem; detecting the button press, or generating pseudo-random numbers(that's not trivial, but perhaps for your case something simple will suffice) ?

Comment: My problem is: When I press the button once, sometimes I get two or three random numbers not only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what you are looking for is "signal debouncing".

When you press the button, the signal does not go right from low to high value, but is noisy on onset(that's a general property of mechanical contacts), creating multiple "button presses". Common and working approach is:

1) button press detected(transition from 0 to 1 on your input pin)

2) delay(10) // wait for a few milliseconds

3) check the button again to see if it's still pressed; if true, the button was really pressed, if not then it was just some noise and can be ignored

This will reject any pulse shorter than 10 ms

Here is a short video describing what actually happens when you press the button: https://youtu.be/jYOYgU2vlSE

And an article along with code: https://programmingelectronics.com/tutorial-19-debouncing-a-button-with-arduino-old-version/